# Send Message In Specific Channel In cogs discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i m trying to send a message in specific channel ...i know how to specify channel normally but i m getting very confused in cogs i m really not able to understand how to do so....any help is appreciated :)

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(ctx, channel:discord.Channel=None):
        channel = '785465306470547457'
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Orange")
        message = await ctx.send_message(channel, "React to me!")
        while True:
            reaction = await ctx.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=message)
            await ctx.add_roles(reaction.message.author, role)
```

**ERROR**

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.rolesystem' raised an error: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In classes (unless it's a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`) functions always take `self` as the first argument
2. `on_ready` doesn't take any arguments
3. It's `discord.TextChannel` not `discord.Channel` also use this only *in commands*
4. ID's are integers and channels must be `abc.Messageable` object not `string`
5. You didn't define `user`, also `server` has been renamed to `guild` in version `1.0.0`
6. It's `ctx.send` not `ctx.send_message`
7. It's `bot.wait_for` not `ctx.wait_for_reaction`

Also, what's the while loop suppose to do?

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    """This will wait for someone to react with ``
    and add him a role
  
    Note: This will wait only for one reaction"""

    channel_id = 785465306470547457 
    # Getting the channel
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    # Getting the role
    role = discord.utils.get(channel.guild.roles, name='Orange')
    # Sending the message
    message = await channel.send('React to me')

    def check(reaction, user):
        """Checks if the reaction message is the one sent before
        and if the reaction is ``"""
        return reaction.message == message and str(reaction) == ''

    # Waiting for the reaction
    reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    # Adding the role
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Note: This code **will not** work unless you enable default intents and `intents.members` [here's an introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents) to intents.

Please **read** the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it's really helpful and learn more **python** and **OOP** before diving into `discord.py`.

Also, from the code, I suppose you want to send a static message, and when someone reacts, add him a role, use the  [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event for that

Reference:

- [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_ready#discord.on_ready)
- [bot.get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)
- [TextChannel.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.TextChannel.send)
- [bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: actually i was just in a problem with sending message in specific channels in cog ....and it was just a random code which i could present the problem in .....i havent reach so far but still you did much for me ☺Thanks thanks thanks a lot and it helped me a lot thanks

Comment: also as u have done a lot the last thing is it shows error 
**reaction, user = self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object**
i m sorry i dont know much but adding this feature is urgent

Comment: it Worked Thanks so so so much :D